# Press buttons by swiping finger (for piano effect)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a piano-like app where every button plays a note. My UIButtons play sound on Touch Down event. The problem arises when I'm swiping finger from one button to another (imagine swiping your finger against piano keys to capture all notes in between), which still "holds" the first button without touching another, unless I lift my finger.

How do you capture multiple Touch Down events without ever lifting your finger?

Comment: Any solution you find for it ?? I am having the same requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional targets to your button like this:

```
myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(yourMethodHere:withEvent: )
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

Here is a list of the type of events you can use:

```
enum {
   UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,
   UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,
   UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
   UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
   UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
   UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
   UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
   UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
   UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

   UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,

   UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,
   UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
   UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,

   UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,
   UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,
   UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,
   UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,
   UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

Then you can have a function like this:

```
-(void) yourMethodHere:(UIControl *) button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not achieve what you want by just handling touch event just on your buttons. I suggest to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to handle user's swiping finger. And you can check which button has been swiped, then play corresponding music.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on gesture recognizers will help you quite a bit:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more